# Delphi QuickReport: print number of grouped records

Tags: delphi, quickreports

In QuickReport 3 and Delphi, how do you print the number of records that where grouped by the `TQRBand` type `GroupFooter`?

Does it involve expression and Count? Thanks.

EDIT: could be named as "generate a subtotal for each group".

Let's say we have

```
<header>
<title>
<group header>
<deail>
<deail>
<deail>
<group footer> print here 3

<group header>
<deail>
<deail>
<group footer> print here 2

<summary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just do this yourself?  Make a memory variable **iDetail: Integer**  You will have to reinitialize it to zero in the applicable **OnBeforePrint** method handler.  Then where you want it to print do a **inttostr(idetail)**.

I have found QuickReport to have many limitations where you have to program stuff like this yourself.

Comment: this is doable however it breaks the use of bands in quick report. i will have to maintain the code with changes in the report. if all else fail, ill result to this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I write this by mix of memory and QR help reading... I have no QR at hand to test what I say, so it's up to you to test *before* accepting my answer ;)

Drop a TQRExpr component on your footer band for that group.  Then locate the Expression property in Object inspector and you may want to click on the ellipsis button to launch the expression editor and build a new expression using the count function.

Or you may want to enter the expression manually, like 'Count(<del>Table1.Field1</del>)'

Set the ResetAfterPrint property to true to instruct the component put the counter at 0 before a new group starts.

You may want to use the Mask property to format that number.

**Edit**
@none states Count does not take any arguments, so I deleted the one I originally enclosed in the parenthesis, but I'm not sure if you must use the parenthesis itself or not (I have no way to test it). If you're interested in use **count** instead of *reinventing the wheel*, please comment if it works as shown now -or not-.

Comment: im not sure that count takes arguments.

Comment: Count Does not take any argument. this answer should be deleted.

Comment: @none: As I said, I wrote this by memory and help file.  If count does not take any argument, documentation is not clear at that point and I remembered it takes one, as my memory tends to be very bad on such small details.  Despite that I think this answer will remain because I see no reason to delete it.  Regards.

Comment: the reason i suggested it for deletion is when another guy pass by to see if this solution works, and waste time trying.

Comment: @none: Is supposed people will try the accepted answer first.  If someone also wants to try my suggestion, better if I edit my answer to state it does not take any arguments, so thanks for the info ;)

Comment: you clearly don't understand that use of Count is not for the band attached , rather the band the expression is on. this solution will not solve the question proposed, qr is poorly documented to state what count does, and that is not your fault.